# Bandwidth Reporting and Usage Reporting Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I've tried Googling for a while but did not have any luck on this...

Does anyone know if there's a nodejs library (or a way to do this with core node modules) in order to monitor network bandwidth (for download throughput and upload throughput) on a windows PC (I'm not necessarily trying to calculate the bandwidth usage of a web server - just the bandwidth usage of the host computer that's running the script). I've searched through the Internet and came across a decent GUI-based tool called networx, but I was wondering if there's a way to make a very simple nodejs program that does what networx can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WMI exposes the system's network metrics.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394340(v=vs.85).aspx)

There's a [wmi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wmi) module for node, which you should be able to use to get the system's total bandwidth usage.

Comment: I've tried install wmi module but I've been getting an error saying that uid must be an unsigned int. Have you ever run into this issue before? I've posted the npm-debug.log message here:http://pastie.org/private/v0pokf974chwfuldrmd50w

Comment: I couldn't get the issue fixed, but I went around it by directly npm installing from the wmi link.

Comment: Looks like a [npm issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4080#issuecomment-64096878).

Comment: Thanks josh3736, have you ever worked with this library before? I'm not exactly a javascript expert and never worked with windows wmi before so I'm having difficult time understanding how to use the library. It looks like this library doesn't have a documentation, making it a bit more harder for me to understand.